# Cross-domain XHR with cordova-plugin-whitelist on PGB is Failing

Tags: ajax, cordova, xmlhttprequest, phonegap-build

Using :

1. PGB cli-5.2.0
2. cordova-plugin-whitelist (i've tried both https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/4178  and plugins/3401 )
3. Refering to ( https://github.com/lukesmith123/whitelist-2/blob/18a8ce4/README.md ) i added `<allow-navigation href="*" />` , `<allow-intent href="*" />`, `<access origin="*" />`
4. My app is using an ajax request to get data from `http` that has `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"`.

But still get: Error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404, yet on localhost it works just fine.

What could i be missing?

Comment: Please post the code where you have trouble with! Thank you.

Comment: @LeonidGlanz here is the code :

`$(document).ready(function () {
 
 $.ajax({
   url: '***',//<<< My http URL that has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
   type: 'GET',
   crossDomain: true,
   dataType: 'xml',
   success: function(data){
    $(data).find('EpisodesList Episode').each(function(){
     
     var episodeTitle = $(this).find('Title').text();
     
     $( ".latest_episodeTitle1" ).append( episodeTitle );
     
    });
   },
   error: function(){
    $( 'Show relevant error' ).appendTo( "#err_dialog" );
   },
  });
 
});`

Comment: Finally got it working.

I put this **CSR metta tag** in the html `<head>`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src *  'unsafe-inline'; script-src *  'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`

And put this  **cordova-plugin-whitelist** in the **config.xml**

`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />`

Phew!!!

Comment: So you could answer your own question to help others.

Comment: @LeonidGlanz thanks, i've answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.

I put this **CSR metta tag** in the html `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src *  'unsafe-inline'; script-src *  'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

And put this  **cordova-plugin-whitelist** in the **config.xml**

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Phew!!!